# Java manupilate an object in a list with the stream method

Tags: java, list, dictionary, foreach, java-stream

I have a class called Employee that has the following: firstName, lastName, salary and position, and I would like to practice the stream method and manipulate the data in my object like I want to count how many upper case letters in the first name of the employee but my problem is I get the object as a whole object and if I want to loop through it using the foreach method to get one instance of my object I cant do anything after that as the foreach is terminal operation, so how can I loop through the list get each employee first name and check how many uppercase letters does it contain.
Here is what I have been trying to do:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        emp.setFirstName("John");
        emp.setLastName("Mark");
        emp.setPosition("dev");
        emp.setSalary(1000);

        list.add(emp);
        list.stream().forEach(i -> i.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(isLower(list));

    }

    public static String isLower(List<Employee> empList) {
        System.out.println("I am here");
        Stream<Employee> stream = empList.stream();
        return stream.map(i -> i.getFirstName()).toString();
    }

    static boolean isDigit(char[] ch) {
        System.out.println("I am here2");
        for (char c : ch)
            return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
        return false;

    }

    static boolean isLowerCase(char[] ch) {
        for (char c : ch)
            return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
        return false;
    }

    static boolean isUpperCase(char[] ch) {
        for (char c : ch)
            return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
        return false;
    }

}
```

Sorry for such a silly question but I am a beginner in Java and trying to learn

Comment: Note: `list.stream().forEach(i -> i.getFirstName());` is going to do essentially nothing, as stream methods never modify the underlying data structure.

Comment: What do you expect `Stream.toString()` to return?

Comment: What's the relevance of `isDigit()` and `isLowerCase()` and `isUpperCase()`?

Comment: @mc10 but im still not trying to modify anything here am just trying to get the firstName

Comment: @shmosel Im still not using these methods but I would like to use them to return true if the string(firstName) contains either digit or uppercase or letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I loop through the list get each employee first name and check
>   how many uppercase letters does it contain

To count the no of uppercase letters in the firstname of each employee

```
list.stream()
    .map(Employee::getFirstName)
    .mapToInt(s -> s.split("[A-Z]", -1).length - 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

total uppercase letters

```
list.stream()
    .map(Employee::getFirstName)
    .mapToInt(s -> s.split("[A-Z]", -1).length - 1)
    .sum();
```

Comment: thank you very much that's what I am looking for, can you advice me with a good reference to learn these functions from?

Comment: And why do I get zero if I changed the regx from [A-Z] to [a-z] thats if I wanted to count the lowercase letters

Comment: @KhaledJamal, there was a small issue, updated the answer. it should work fine now.

Comment: yeah now its working fine can you explain a little bit what is going on?

Comment: Plz take a look at split function - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: The use of the split function seems more than a little hackish.  I'd write `mapToLong(s -> s.chars().filter(c -> Character.isUpperCase((char) c)).count())`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: you don’t need lambdas with type casts. You can just use `s -> s.codePoints().filter(Character::isUpperCase).count()` or do the entire operation in a single stream: `list.stream() .map(Employee::getFirstName) .flatMapToInt(String::codePoints) .filter(Character::isUpperCase) .count();`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `Character.isUpperCase` took a code point overload as well as a `char` overload.